# List different variations between two tables in a series

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables called Transaction1 and Transaction2 and they have different steps:

```
Create Table Transaction1
(
    Step varchar(100)
)

Create Table Transaction2
(
    Step varchar(100)
)

Insert into Transaction1 (Step) values
('Read the value from row 4.'),
('Multiply that value times 2.'),
('Write the result to row 3.'),
('Write the literal value “5” to row 2.'),
('Write the literal value “100” to row 5.'),
('Commit.')

Insert into Transaction2 (Step) values
('Read the value from row 2.'),
('Write that value to row 4.'),
('Write the literal value “10” to row 3.'),
('Commit.')
```

However, I would like to list out different variations in the rows and these variations must happen sequentially. For instance, One possible variation that I have identified is:
[image]

Likewise, I am sure that there will be many different variations and I am not sure how I can achieve that with SQL. I though of using cartesian product like this:

```
Select t1.*, t2.* from Transaction1 t1, Transaction2 t2
```

But this one is not keeping the steps sequentially. How would it be possible to achieve a sequential output with both transactions with SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What identifies the sequence? You need to store something to determine this.

Comment: You have no sequential information in the tables.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: And you want `union all` not a cross join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're looking for 2^4=16 combinations.  The code assigns ordinal numbers to each row of the input.  Then CROSS JOIN creates each combination of columns and assigns a unique 'combo' number using ROW_NUMBER().  Finally, the result is UNPIVOTED using CROSS APPLY into 16 combinations of 5 columns.  The final 2 elements in the sequence (9 and 10) come from the Transaction1 table.  Something like this

```
drop table if exists #Transaction1
go
Create Table #Transaction1(
    ordinal int,
    Step varchar(100));

drop table if exists #Transaction2
go
Create Table #Transaction2(
    ordinal int,
    Step varchar(100));

Insert into #Transaction1 (ordinal, Step) values
(1,'Read the value from row 4.'),
(2,'Multiply that value times 2.'),
(3,'Write the result to row 3.'),
(4,'Write the literal value “5” to row 2.'),
(5,'Write the literal value “100” to row 5.'),
(6,'Commit.');

Insert into #Transaction2 (ordinal, Step) values
(1,'Read the value from row 2.'),
(2,'Write that value to row 4.'),
(3,'Write the literal value “10” to row 3.'),
(4,'Commit.');

with
c1_cte(trans, ordinal, step) as (
    select 1, ordinal, step from #Transaction1 where ordinal=1
    union all
    select 2, ordinal, step from #Transaction2 where ordinal=1),
c2_cte(trans, ordinal, step) as (
    select 1, ordinal, step from #Transaction1 where ordinal=2
    union all
    select 2, ordinal, step from #Transaction2 where ordinal=2),
c3_cte(trans, ordinal, step) as (
    select 1, ordinal, step from #Transaction1 where ordinal=3
    union all
    select 2, ordinal, step from #Transaction2 where ordinal=3),
c4_cte(trans, ordinal, step) as (
    select 1, ordinal, step from #Transaction1 where ordinal=4
    union all
    select 2, ordinal, step from #Transaction2 where ordinal=4),
cols_cte as (
    select c1.trans t1, c1.ordinal o1, c1.step s1,
           c2.trans t3, c2.ordinal o3, c2.step s3,
           c3.trans t5, c3.ordinal o5, c3.step s5,
           c4.trans t7, c4.ordinal o7, c4.step s7
    from c1_cte c1
         cross join c2_cte c2
         cross join c3_cte c3
         cross join c4_cte c4),
both_cte as (
    select c.t1, c.o1, c.s1,
           seq2.t2, seq2.o2, seq2.s2,
           c.t3, c.o3, c.s3,
           seq4.t4, seq4.o4, seq4.s4,
           c.t5, c.o5, c.s5,
           seq6.t6, seq6.o6, seq6.s6,
           c.t7, c.o7, c.s7,
           seq8.t8, seq8.o8, seq8.s8,
           row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn
    from cols_cte c
         cross apply (select trans t2, ordinal o2, step s2 
                      from c1_cte cc where cc.trans<>c.t1) seq2
         cross apply (select trans t4, ordinal o4, step s4 
                      from c2_cte cc where cc.trans<>c.t3) seq4
         cross apply (select trans t6, ordinal o6, step s6 
                      from c3_cte cc where cc.trans<>c.t5) seq6
         cross apply (select trans t8, ordinal o8, step s8 
                      from c4_cte cc where cc.trans<>c.t7) seq8),
unq_combo_cte as (select distinct rn from both_cte),
t1_last_cte(combo, seq, trans, ordinal, step) as (
    select uc.rn, t1.ordinal+4, 1, t1.ordinal, t1.step
    from unq_combo_cte uc
         cross join #Transaction1 t1
    where t1.ordinal in(5, 6))
select v.*
from both_cte b
     cross apply (values (b.rn, 1, b.t1, b.o1, b.s1),
                         (b.rn, 2, b.t2, b.o2, b.s2),
                         (b.rn, 3, b.t3, b.o3, b.s3),
                         (b.rn, 4, b.t4, b.o4, b.s4),
                         (b.rn, 5, b.t5, b.o5, b.s5),
                         (b.rn, 6, b.t6, b.o6, b.s6),
                         (b.rn, 7, b.t7, b.o7, b.s7),
                         (b.rn, 8, b.t8, b.o8, b.s8)) 
                         v(combo, seq, trans, ordinal, step)
union all select * from t1_last_cte
order by combo, seq;
```

```
combo   seq trans   ordinal step
1   1   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
1   2   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
1   3   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
1   4   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
1   5   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
1   6   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
1   7   2   4   Commit.
1   8   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
1   9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
1   10  1   6   Commit.
2   1   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
2   2   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
2   3   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
2   4   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
2   5   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
2   6   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
2   7   2   4   Commit.
2   8   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
2   9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
2   10  1   6   Commit.
3   1   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
3   2   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
3   3   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
3   4   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
3   5   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
3   6   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
3   7   2   4   Commit.
3   8   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
3   9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
3   10  1   6   Commit.
4   1   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
4   2   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
4   3   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
4   4   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
4   5   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
4   6   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
4   7   2   4   Commit.
4   8   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
4   9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
4   10  1   6   Commit.
5   1   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
5   2   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
5   3   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
5   4   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
5   5   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
5   6   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
5   7   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
5   8   2   4   Commit.
5   9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
5   10  1   6   Commit.
6   1   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
6   2   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
6   3   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
6   4   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
6   5   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
6   6   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
6   7   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
6   8   2   4   Commit.
6   9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
6   10  1   6   Commit.
7   1   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
7   2   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
7   3   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
7   4   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
7   5   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
7   6   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
7   7   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
7   8   2   4   Commit.
7   9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
7   10  1   6   Commit.
8   1   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
8   2   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
8   3   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
8   4   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
8   5   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
8   6   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
8   7   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
8   8   2   4   Commit.
8   9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
8   10  1   6   Commit.
9   1   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
9   2   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
9   3   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
9   4   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
9   5   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
9   6   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
9   7   2   4   Commit.
9   8   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
9   9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
9   10  1   6   Commit.
10  1   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
10  2   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
10  3   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
10  4   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
10  5   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
10  6   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
10  7   2   4   Commit.
10  8   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
10  9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
10  10  1   6   Commit.
11  1   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
11  2   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
11  3   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
11  4   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
11  5   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
11  6   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
11  7   2   4   Commit.
11  8   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
11  9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
11  10  1   6   Commit.
12  1   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
12  2   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
12  3   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
12  4   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
12  5   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
12  6   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
12  7   2   4   Commit.
12  8   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
12  9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
12  10  1   6   Commit.
13  1   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
13  2   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
13  3   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
13  4   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
13  5   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
13  6   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
13  7   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
13  8   2   4   Commit.
13  9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
13  10  1   6   Commit.
14  1   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
14  2   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
14  3   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
14  4   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
14  5   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
14  6   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
14  7   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
14  8   2   4   Commit.
14  9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
14  10  1   6   Commit.
15  1   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
15  2   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
15  3   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
15  4   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
15  5   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
15  6   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
15  7   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
15  8   2   4   Commit.
15  9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
15  10  1   6   Commit.
16  1   2   1   Read the value from row 2.
16  2   1   1   Read the value from row 4.
16  3   1   2   Multiply that value times 2.
16  4   2   2   Write that value to row 4.
16  5   1   3   Write the result to row 3.
16  6   2   3   Write the literal value “10” to row 3.
16  7   1   4   Write the literal value “5” to row 2.
16  8   2   4   Commit.
16  9   1   5   Write the literal value “100” to row 5.
16  10  1   6   Commit.
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I would like to incorporate the last two elements from Transaction1 and to balance it off, i added some elements to Transaction2. I have tried to do that and the results are not what I expected: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b6f5c421615dcf50afebc27ce184fdbe

If you run the results, you will see that for combination 1, the "Commit" from Transaction1 is omitted and the "Commit" from Transaction2 appears twice which isn't correct and I am not sure where I am wrong. I would appreciate if you could take a look at this. Thanks

Comment: 9 and 10 have been added

Comment: Thanks...this is great. Quick question, from the results, why does step 6 of transaction ("Commit") always come last? it is possible that transaction 2 could complete first and then transaction 1 which isn't the case that I see here. But this is a great work and i greatly appreciate it.